# Determine if Attachment field is empty

Tags: vba, ms-access, attachment, ms-access-2013, attachment-field

How can you determine if in Attachment field in Access does not contain an attachment using VBA? I tried

```
If IsNull(rstMassBalance.Fields("FileName"))
```

and

```
If rstMassBalance.Fields("FileName") = Null
```

but neither of these work. It either does nothing or gives me run-time error 3021 that says "No current record"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't use the `Attachments` field, but the attachments are retrieved into a `Recordset2` from the `Value` property of the attachments-field.

```
Dim rsChild As DAO.Recordset2

Set rsChild = rstMassBalance.Fields("FileName").Value
```

I'm not sure if this will return `Nothing` or an empty recordset if there are no attachments. So either:

```
If rsChild Is Nothing Then
'or 
If rsChild.RecordCount  <= 0 Then   'probably this one
```

There is a lot of information to be garnered from this [Access Blog](http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-access/archive/2007/08/24/adding-removing-and-saving-files-from-the-new-attachment-field-in-access-2007.aspx).

[Work with Attachments in DAO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835669%28v=office.14%29.aspx) suggests that you could check:

```
If rsChild.EOF Then
```

Comment: I tried that and rsChild does in fact equal nothing, which I can see while debugging, however, I can not do Set rsChild = rstMassBalance.Fields("FileName").Value because it says there is no current record

Comment: UPDATE: I got it to work. You don't actually need to use a child recordset of the attachment field, if you simply do 'If rstMassBalance.RecordCount <= 0' that works. Thanks for your help.